# django model use database server time

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have 2 separate django server and a mysql server at difference location

Using django model, when try create/update object (as code below). Result is both 3 column with the same django server local time value. How to get db server local time when do that.

my model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    test = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

My code:

```
y = Test()
y.test = datetime.now()
y.save()
```

result

```
    id  create               update               test                  
------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------------- 
     6  2013-10-07 06:57:04  2013-10-07 06:57:04  2013-10-07 06:57:04
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?  It's generally a good idea to store times in UTC and then convert to the appropriate time zone during presentation.

Comment: The reason is I have one db server for few web server. for consistent, all data should use db server time

Comment: @Hardy have you tried django database function's Now() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#now have you solved it? if yes how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

If you handle this in Django, django will set these fields before saving the data to database. In that case, Django will set the time according to your applicaiton server (server which django runs).

You must make some settings to your MySql installation (if you have not set them already). Then you must re-create your tables or alter them in your database (I guess Django model definition can not handle this). This is a [how-to doc explaning these settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

An example sql `CREATE TABLE`  statement will look like that

```
CREATE TABLE test_test (
    create DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    update DATETIME DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

If you already have data in yotr table, then you may execute ALTERs' instead of re-creating tables.

Then you must edit yor models and set related datetime fields to null, so MySql can set them.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    create = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    test = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do what you want without setting up the database timezone. Let's see what means each of your dates:

```
create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

It sets automatically the date to the time when you add it.

```
update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It sets automatically the date to the time when you start the process (either web process or command).

```
test = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
...
y.test = datetime.now()
```

It sets the date to the time of the process (where Django process run).

To get the database time, you could store the timezone of database in settings, and use it whenever neccesary. You can't use any automatically generated field for this.

Another solution could be to grab local time manually (through a raw query) on database.